# Change JPanel size via JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I have a JDialog with a JButton (right box in screenshot). When I click the JButton I want to change the size of the JPanel in another JFrame (left box in screenshot).

My problem is, that currently my application does not change the size of the JPanel to the new size (20, 20), when i click the button "click me". My testtext "Hello world" appears in the console when I click the button.

**Example Screenshot:**

Alternative link if screenshot is not displayed: http://www.dachaufsetzer.net/files/images/other/java-question-1.jpg

Here is my code:

**Dialog.java** (the JDialog)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener{

    public Dialog(){
        JDialog d = new JDialog();

        d.setSize(300, 300);

        JButton b = new JButton("click me");
        b.addActionListener(new Generator());
        d.add(b);


        d.setVisible(true);


    } 

}
```

**Generator.java** (the JPanel which is used in Frame.java)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Generator extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    int width;
    int height;

    public Generator(){

    }

    public Generator(int w, int h){

        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;

        super.setBackground(Color.red);
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }  
}
```

**Frame.java** (the JFrame which uses Generator.java)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame(){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(400, 400);

        Generator g = new Generator(2000, 2000);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(g);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        f.add(scrollPane);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

**Main.java** (the main class)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame window = new Frame();
        Dialog d = new Dialog();

    }    
}
```

Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing things that have no sense.

About the `Frame` class:

In your `Frame` class you are creating another JFrame object in the constructor making the `Frame` class useless. You also need to save a reference of the `Generator` panel you added to the Frame ScrollPane to change its size from the `Dialog`. This is the `Frame` class with the changes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Generator g;

    public Frame(){
        setSize(400, 400);
        g = new Generator(2000, 2000);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(g);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        add(scrollPane);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

About the `Dialog` class:

You have done the same mistake. You are creating another `JDialog` object into the `Dialog` class constructor. Another huge mistake is that you are adding a `new Generator()` as action listener to the button. To change the size of the `Generator` panel that you add to the `Frame` you need to get the reference of that panel and add it as ActionListener. This is the `Dialog` class with the changes:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener{

    public Dialog(Generator g){
        setSize(300, 300);
        JButton b = new JButton("click me");
        b.addActionListener(g);
        add(b);
        setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

As you can see, now the `Dialog` constructor has `Generator` as parameter. This parameter is the panel you want to change.

Then in your Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame window = new Frame();
        //Here you send to Dialog constructor the panel you add to the Frame
        Dialog d = new Dialog(window.g);
    }    
}
```

When you create an instance of a class by using `new`, this instance has its properties that are different from other instances of the same type. In your code you are creating more than one instance of the same type, thinking that changing one of them will change the other (I think you don't actually understand that they are two separate things).

Comment: Thank you very much Flood2d for your great help. Now it is clear!

Answer (score 1):

In the `ActionListener` code you also need to invoke `revalidate()` after resetting the preferred size. This will invoke the layout manager.

You may also need to invoke `repaint()` after the `revalidate()`.

Of course this will only change the panel size. The dialog size will stay the same. You may also need to invoke `pack()` on the dialog if you want it to resize. You can get a reference to the dialog by using the `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...)` in your ActionListener.

Comment: Thanks camickr for you support, with your and the feedback from Flood2d it works